# React Js create-react-app scripts not working

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm getting this error while trying to run npm start, which is a by default script that came in with create-react-app.

```
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn powershell',
  path: 'powershell',
  spawnargs: [
    '-NoProfile',
    '-NonInteractive',
    '–ExecutionPolicy',
    'Bypass',
    '-EncodedCommand',
    'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBgACIAaAB0AHQAcAA6AC8ALwBsAG8AYwBhAGwAaABvAHMAdAA6ADMAMAAwADAAYAAiACIA'
  ]
}
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Madhu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-17T17_18_54_190Z-debug.log
Waiting for the debugger to disc
```

I searched around a bit, and found that cmd root path must be added to environment variables. I added them but still the error persists.

```
C:\Users\Madhu\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Madhu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Madhu\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Windows\System32\;
```

I'm using an outdated system with windows 7, is this an issue?

Comment: try npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: That's what I did, as mentioned in the official tutorial